# What's the correct way as an "end-user" to access "my" tickets via API v2 of Zendesk

Tags: api, authorization, zendesk

When I try to authenticate against the Zendesk API as an end-user, and then list tickets, it always responds with 403 Forbidden:

e.g.

```
GET
https://mysite.zendesk.com/api/v2/requested.json
Basic Authorization
```

returns with a 403

```
{
    "error": {
        "title": "Forbidden",
        "message": "You do not have access to this page. Please contact the account owner of this help desk for further help."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the "tickets" API (like above) is not for end-users. Instead they must use the "requests" API .

So use: `https://mysite.zendesk.com/api/v2/requests.json` instead...

Comment: Nice tip; thanks. It seems to be a subtle difference. ZD's documentation mentions that agents only have access to the /requested.json endpoint (https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/tickets#listing-tickets), but it doesn't list the end-user alternative. It could probably be clarified.